# In R's Wordspace package, can dist.matrix be altered to handle NA's?

Tags: r, matrix, distance

I have been calculating distance matrices using the function `dist` from Stats. I came across `dist.matrix` from Wordspace, which seems to be MUCH faster for large matrices. However, while `dist` can handle NA's, `dist.matrix` cannot and when there is a missing value fills the whole matrix with NAs.

For example:

```
X <- data.frame(replicate(5,rnorm(100)))
X[1:10, 1] <- NA
X[10:30, 2] <- NA
X[50:55, 3] <- NA

d <- as.matrix(dist(as.matrix(X), method = "euclidean"))
> d[1:6, 1:6]
      1        2        3        4        5        6
1 0.000000 1.434098 2.956302 1.505901 3.172647 2.083671
2 1.434098 0.000000 3.799095 2.326719 3.599186 2.935583
3 2.956302 3.799095 0.000000 2.097622 3.661096 1.455270
4 1.505901 2.326719 2.097622 0.000000 3.995651 0.843491
5 3.172647 3.599186 3.661096 3.995651 0.000000 4.095924
6 2.083671 2.935583 1.455270 0.843491 4.095924 0.000000
```

Whereas:

```
d2 <- dist.matrix(as.matrix(X), method="euclidean")
> d2[1:6, 1:6]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
[2,]  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
[3,]  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
[4,]  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
[5,]  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
[6,]  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

The parameter skip.missing = T doesn't seem to help. In addition, skipping is not the right solution: what `dist` does is scale the distance to reflect the number of non-NA's in a certain pair.

Any ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think there's any NA handling in that package

Comment: It seems like there is no fast/parallel solution that handles NA's on windows :(